# Extract a property slug from a json file

Tags: json, shell, jq, bitbucket-api

I would like to extract the names of the repositories and their size after getting the list of all the repositories in bitbucket using API via shell script. The command I'm using for that is

```
repo_list=$(cat repo.json | jq '.[] | .slug ' | sed 's/"//g')
```

repo.json contains:

```
{
"pagelen":100,
"size":494,
"values":[
  {
     "scm":"git",
     "website":"",
     "fork_policy":"no_public_forks",
     "full_name":"org_name/ecomm-dist-cache",
     "name":"ecomm-dist-cache",
     "language":"java",
     "created_on":"2014-11-18T19:01:25.741787+00:00",
     "mainbranch":{
        "type":"branch",
        "name":"master"
     },
     "workspace":{
        "slug":"org_name",
        "type":"workspace",
        "name":"Org Name ",
        "uuid":"{xxxxxxxxxxxxx}"
     },
     "has_issues":true,
     "updated_on":"2018-06-06T22:17:02.947496+00:00",
     "size":105095621,
     "type":"repository",
     "slug":"ecomm-dist-cache",
     "is_private":true,
     "description":"Initial Migration of ecomm-dist-cache"
  },
  {
     "scm":"git",
     "website":"",
     "full_name":"org_name/mqfte_ecommoutboundtransfertoweddingchannel",
     "name":"MQFTE_ECOMMOutboundTransferToWeddingChannel",
     "language":"",
     "mainbranch":{
        "type":"branch",
        "name":"master"
     },
     "workspace":{
        "slug":"org_name",
        "type":"workspace",
        "name":"Org Name ",
        "uuid":"{xxxxxxxxxxxxx}"
     },
     "has_issues":false,
     "size":99549,
     "type":"repository",
     "slug":"mqfte_ecommoutboundtransfertoweddingchannel",
     "is_private":true,
     "description":""
  }
],
"page":1,
"next":"https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/org_name? pagelen=100&page=2"
}
```

The error msg I'm getting is

```
Cannot index number with string "slug"
```

Expected result is

```
ecomm-dist-cache
mqfte_ecommoutboundtransfertoweddingchannel
```

Comment: Provide a valid JSON, yours is _not_. Check in https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: You have tagged `jq`, so I'm assuming you want to parse a JSON content, which would mean a proper JSON file is indeed needed

Comment: @Inian I've provided the proper JSON file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jq -r '.values[].slug' repo.json
```

-r will remove the quotation marks and so there is no need to pipe through to sed.

Comment: is it possible to get multiple values in a single line? like

ecomm-dist-cache - 105095621
mqfte_ecommoutboundtransfertoweddingchannel - 99549

slug - size